# Evaluate the integral of sec(2x + 1) dx

Tags: calculus, integration

I got $\ln|\sec(2x +1) + \tan(2x+1)| + \text C$ as an answer. I saw that the integral of $\sec x$ is $\ln|\sec x + \tan x| + \text C$. But I feel I may have left something out because that was too easy.

Answer (score 1):

Set $2x+1=u\implies 2dx=du$

$$\int\sec(2x+1)\ dx=\frac12\int\sec u\ du=\frac{\ln|\sec u+\tan u|}2+K$$

Replace back $u$ with $2x+1$

Answer (score 0):

You neglected the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \ln|\sec(2x+1)+\tan(2x+1)| = \sec(2x+1)\cdot 2.
$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : Absolutely right --- my mind was on _anti_differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\sec({2x+1})\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int\sec({2x+1})\,d(2x+1)$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=2x+1$. Then $\text du=2$
$$\int \sec(2x+1) \ \text dx=\int \frac{\sec(u)}{2} \ \text du$$
$$=\frac 12\int \sec(u) \, \text du$$
$$=\frac 12\ln|\sec(u)+\tan(u)|+\text C$$
Reverse the substitution
$$\frac 12\ln|\sec(2x+1)+\tan(2x+1)|+\text C$$
$$\color{green}{\int \sec(2x+1) \, \text dx =\frac 12\ln|\sec(2x+1)+\tan(2x+1)|+\text C}$$